# Vuepress build failed after migrating from 0.X to 1.2.0

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, vuepress

I followed the official upgrade guide on vuepress website. https://vuepress.vuejs.org/miscellaneous/migration-guide.html

When I run `yarn docs:dev` I got this output:

```
tip Apply theme @vuepress/theme-default ...
tip Apply plugin container (i.e. "vuepress-plugin-container") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/last-updated (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-last-updated") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/register-components (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-register-components") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/active-header-links (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-active-header-links") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/search (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-search") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/nprogress (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-nprogress") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/pwa (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-pwa") ...
tip Apply plugin vuepress-plugin-anonymous-3d39fa1d ...

* Client █████████████████████████ building (42%) 271/275 modules 4 active
 node_modules\lodash\_root.js

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /docs/
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from c:\dsasd\docs\.vuepress\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
Language does not exist bat
```

When I open port 8080 in browser, it displays bunch of errors.

When I run `yarn docs:build` I got this output:

```
Error: Failed to compile with errors.
    at webpack (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\lib\node\build\index.js:186:16)
    at finalCallback (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiCompiler.js:254:12)
    at runWithDependencies.err (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiCompiler.js:277:6)
    at done (c:\dsasd\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2931:13)
    at runCompilers (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiCompiler.js:181:48)
    at err (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiCompiler.js:188:7)
    at compiler.run (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\MultiCompiler.js:270:7)
    at finalCallback (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:257:39)
    at hooks.done.callAsync.err (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:273:13)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (c:\dsasd\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:33:1)  
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (c:\dsasd\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at onCompiled (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:271:21)
    at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (c:\dsasd\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)   
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (c:\dsasd\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at compilation.seal.err (c:\dsasd\node_modules\@vuepress\core\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Any solution or suggestions?

Comment: Can you share more detail about your project? Maybe a repo? It's hard to tell just from your log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think there is a conflict in your dependence that is causing the errors. Remove every dependence in your `package.json` except `vuepress`, reinstall all dependencies and the error disappears. I'm not familiar with this, but I think it may be a problem with the versioning of `core-js`, `vuepress` is still using **2.x** and you are using **3.x**

The other problem with migrating to `vuepress` **1.2.0** is that some of the official plugins are not shipped with `vuepress` by default. So you need to manually install [vuepress-plugin-pwa](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/official/plugin-pwa.html#vuepress-plugin-pwa) to use it. Check out the [document](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/#out-of-the-box) for more detail.

BTW, I notice that you have both `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` in your repo, so I'm not sure which tool are you using. Currently, `yarn` is the recommended way, because `npm` could cause some errors in certain circumstances.

Comment: Ya, it's true. Vuepress is still using core-js beta which was giving me security errors.